# Facebook js sdk: redirect_uri property

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a problem with FB.ui method - I'm trying to show dialog (feed) and then redirect my user to some url, like this:

```
FB.ui({
  title: 'some title', 
  display: 'iframe',
  method: 'feed',
  caption: 'some caption',
  message: 'some message',
  redirect_uri: 'http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/'
});
```

But when I use this property (redirect_uri) dialog loading stucks, and in firebug I can see that an error occurred: Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Answer (score 3):

you could try the callback function:

```
FB.ui({
      title: 'some title', 
      display: 'iframe',
      method: 'feed',
      caption: 'some caption',
      message: 'some message'
    },
    function(){
        top.location.href = "http://apps.facebook.com/my_app";
    }
);
```